# Passing arguments between Jade templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

I'm working on a small CMS system as a warm-up to Node.js websites with Express, Jade and Bootstrap, and I've ran into a small problem.

I'm using includes for various parts of the page, such as navigation header, etc., to make the website as modular as possible. I did the static part of the admin interface, and now would begin to add the dynamic, and there's the problem.

For example, if I wanted to create an accordion-enabled user list, right now I'd have to do the following:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= 'My Awesome Website | ' + title
    include imports/bootstrap
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/style.css')
  body
    include include/navbar
    .container-fluid
      include include/sidebar-admin

      ul.list-user
      each user in users
        li.user
          h3.user.user-header= user.name
          //etc
```

Instead of this, I'd like to move the whole li.user block into a separate jade file, and do this:

```
ul.list-user
  each user in users
    include include/userlistitem
```

But for some reason, the variable user does not get passed down to the include. Is there any way to force it to the included file to have a specific variable, or it is not implemented yet?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using a [Mixin](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#mixins)?

Comment: Mixins would be fine but they won't work through includes for some reason, at least on my end.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, which does not work via a direct include:
Render the HTML in the controller and add it to the "user" instance.

Example:

in controller:

```
user.html = jade.renderFile("views/_userlistitem.jade",{name:value});
```

in JADE file:

```
ul.list-user
   each user in users
      #{user.html}
```